# How to shorten these code about copying what one text file has to another text file?

Tags: python-3.x

The code is from online python book Learn Python the Hard Way, 3rd Edition.pdf.

I want to know other ways to shorten the code in a way that it will give the same output.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print ("Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file))

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print ("The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata))

print ("Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file))
print ("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, ctrl -c to abort.")
input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print ("Alright, all done.")

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: Why would it need to be shorter? Also note https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: Not only it doesn't need to be shorter, but this also does not comply with PEP-8 guidelines-don't put spaces between functions and their arguments and excessive blank lines.

Comment: it's just for exercise purposes, anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just use copyfile from shutil library.